# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format

```
select distinct sko.CONTENTId, 
       sko.HELPDESKID, 
       sko.SEGMENTID, 
       som.SUBMITTED_FOR_NAME, 
       sko.SUBMITTEDDATE, 
       to_date(sko.LASTMODIFIEDDATE, 'DD-MM-RR') 
 from sky_know_obj sko
 join sky_object_mass som 
   on sko.CONTENTId = som.CONTENTId 
where sko.LASTMODIFIEDDATE >  date'2019-11-03' 
  and sko.LASTMODIFIEDDATE <= date'2019-12-03'
```

This is my oracle sql query. i am running it in python. when I run this in the Oracle SQL Developer then it is giving results but whenever I tried to execute it in the pycharm the following error is occuring:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01843: not a valid month

when I run

```
select * from nls_session_parameters;
```

this in oracle sql developer then its showing

```
NLS_DATE_FORMAT  =  DD-MM-RR
```

Answer (score 0):

As you apply `TO_DATE` to `LASTMODIFIEDDATE` column and it fails, it seems that not all values have valid month in that column which means that its datatype isn't `date` but `varchar2`.

SQL Developer doesn't return all rows, but the first 50 (or so). If your query scans the whole table, or rows that weren't displayed initially, then it'll fail. Try to navigate to the last row in returned record set in SQL Developer to see what happens.

On the other hand, if column's datatype is `date`, then don't `to_date` it; there's no point in doing that.

Also, you shouldn't rely on database's settings. Take control over your data and don't specify *string* when meaning *date*. Use date literal, e.g.

```
where lastmodifieddate > date '2019-11-03' -- instead of '03-11-19'
```

Comment: Thanks...Its working now. Dont know why I was using to_date for DATE type .I used  **sko.LASTMODIFIEDDATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01' AND DATE '2020-01-08'** this ..and its working now